How to Access Docusaurus Static Pages Without a Local Server?
I'm using Docusaurus to build a static site, and I want to access the generated pages directly from the file system without running a local server.
Currently, the URLs are structured like /docs/advanced/routing, which works fine when using a server. However, when I try to open the files directly, I can't access the pages correctly.
I've considered manually appending /index.html to each path, but I'm concerned about potential issues with links and navigation.
What I've Tried:
Attempted to manually navigate to index.html files in the browser.
Explored using local server tools like http-server, but I want to avoid running a server if possible.
Considered writing a script to modify paths, but I'm unsure about the implications.
What I'm Looking For:
Is there a way to configure Docusaurus to generate paths that include index.html by default?
Are there any best practices for accessing Docusaurus static pages without a server?
Any insights from developers or the Docusaurus team on handling this scenario?
Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated!
